# Install a specific version of symfony

Tags: symfony

I'm looking to install a specific version of symfony.  The installer installs the latest version of symfony.  I'm looking to install version 4.6.4.

curl -LsS https://symfony.com/installer -o /usr/local/bin/symfony

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! This question appears to be [off-topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) as it is about general computer software, and not programming. This question will be better received if asked on [SuperUser](https://superuser.com/) instead.

Comment: @Jesse for clarification: Symfony is pretty close related to programming ;)

Comment: @Monica please share more details. There is no version 4.6.4 of Symfony, neither is there a version 4.4.6

Comment: Just for info, Monica wants to install a specific version of the Symfony installer.  It is currently at 4.12.8.  No idea why they want an older version.

Comment: Forgive me.  I'm a newbie.  I found the older releases here: https://github.com/symfony/cli/releases/download/v4.6.4/symfony_linux_amd64.gz . I guess I just need to update that installer script to download/install the older version instead.  Feel free to correct me.

Comment: @Monica Unless you are operating in a very tightly controlled environment then there is really no point in using anything but the latest version of the Symfony cli.  In fact, the executable is self updating and will always ask if you want the latest version every time your run it.  Just don't confuse the executable with the actual Symfony framework.

Answer (score 3):

According to the [Symfony doc](https://symfony.com/doc/current/setup.html#symfony-lts-versions), you can install a specific version of Symfony by running one of below commands:

1.if you use symfony

```
symfony new my_project_name --version=4.4
```

2.if you use composer

```
composer create-project symfony/website-skeleton:^4.4 my_project_name
```

And, by the way, you can Check out the [Symfony releases](https://symfony.com/releases) to check the details of any past or future Symfony release. as far as I‌'ve checked there is no 4.6.4 because the latest version of the 4.x branch is 4.4.